# Angular universal button click

Tags: angular, angular-universal

When I use external libraries such as lightbox I can use "isPlatformBrowser" from @angular/common to check if the angular client side has loaded and then I can use the click attribute on a html element to and call the lighbox method. However, I am wondering if I can do this to check if the whole component has finished loading on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) hooks.

Most Likely implmeneting `ngAfterViewInit()`

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views.

component.ts :

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
 // content has now loaded and is visible
}
```